# Laravel 5.5 withChain shared storage

Tags: php, laravel, queue, chain

I need to do something like the next example

```
    App\Jobs\Test::withChain([
       new \App\Jobs\Test1($user),
       new \App\Jobs\Test2($user),
    ])->dispatch($user);
```

But Laravel doesn't have any solutions for saving object state between jobs in queue chain.
Has anyone had the same problem as me?
I need to pass some variables to the parent job, save some states and use them in child jobs

Answer (score 2):

You could save data in a database table or in the cache. What is your use case?

Defining a common key to serialize and cache data between jobs would be my first approach.

Comment: Hi! Yep, I thought about it (storage inside file cache/redis/etc). But maybe there is a more elegant solution

Comment: My case is data analysis and i need to get any data from previous steps(waterfall) to understand what should i do next and notify user about results of analysis

Comment: Have you considered using events to trigger subsequent jobs? Say Job 1 finishes and depending on the result, you could send out an event to start Job 2 or different event to trigger Job 3. With events, you can dispatch with payloads, so that gives you a delivery mechanism to pass data between jobs.

Comment: It's working as you suggested :) But it's still not enough flexible.
I asked in laravel git repo about this improvement. I think it will be great to implement it.
I like JS behavior for the same cases (callback waterfalls/promises)